# how to correct "No database support" warning on metasploit in kali linux

Tags: metasploit

recently is have upgraded metasploit in my kali linux

After typing msfconsole on prompt some warning is showing

though previously it use to start without warning but because of package

dependencies i am not able to downgrade it,

[-] ***rting the MeTasploit Framework console...\

[-] * WARNING: No database support: could not connect to server: Connection refused

```
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting

    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

could not connect to server: Connection refused

```
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

[-] ***

on msf console when i type :
msf5 > use exploit/multi/handler

but in options:
msf5 exploit(multi/handler) > options

only this much is showing what is the problem
Module options (exploit/multi/handler):

Name  Current Setting  Required  Description

---

Exploit target:

Id  Name

---

0   Wildcard Target

msf5 exploit(multi/handler) >

Answer (score 0):

No Database Support query, please do the steps mentioned below:

1. **service --status -all**
2. **service postgresql start**
3. **service postgresql status**

Furthermore, everytime before starting msfconsole:

-**service postgresql start**

Let me know if it works! :)